# Получить индекс элемента Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Использую Owl Carousel 2.3.1. Заполняю слайдер элементами (даты) динамически - js-ом.
Мне нужно найти текущую дату или этот элемент из всего списка, что я делаю при помощи JQuery и сделать его активным.

в owl можно получить индекс, но она срабатывает только при событиях, а мне нужно без событий получить индекс этого элемента и сделать его активным.

Как сделать?

Спасибо.

В этой функции мне надо найти элемент. Взять индекс и сделать его активным.

```
onInitialized: function (event) {
                let index = Number(dateSlider.find('div.owl-item:not(.cloned) div.item[data-date="'+moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') +'"]').parent().index());
                setTimeout(function () {
                    dateSlider.trigger('to.owl.carousel', index, 400);
                }, 200);
            },
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос кусочек кода, в котором это должно работать

Comment: @tutankhamun добавил.